# Several servers working with single MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, multithreading, multitasking

I think of a big project, which gonna take much load on sever resources and bandwidth. It should work with huge MySQL database of different webpages (maybe about 20 million, I hope MySQL can handle such amount of records). But I will need to share the requests to the database between several servers I think, because one single server won't be able to handle such a load. I wonder how big projects like Google or Archive.org are doing this? I thought of primitive method, which is like follows:

1. The MySQL database is located on an independent standalone server.
2. The MySQL database table contains a field, say, "server", with particular server name, for which the record is allocated for processing.
3. Each server connects MySQL server and works ONLY with records, which are allocated to that server (by looking into "server" field in that table).

I feel like this is a noob method, but I would like to know your opinion, and maybe the ways you see how this can be implemented in more optimized and clever form.

Will be happy for any tip.

Thanks,
Dennis.

Answer (score 1):

> (maybe about 20 million, I hope MySQL
>   can handle such amount of records)

20M records is next to nothing for a database. It's all about how your use the database, how to write your SQL, your datamodel, etc. etc. Don't worry about 20M records, that's not going to be any problem at all.

Comment: well, I basically understand handling 20M records is all about db optimization, disk space and processor. The main question is how to manage several servers access to the database, because the pages should be subject to near permanent re-indexation, and this should grab a lot of resource, thus I need several servers to handle this task. And the question is how to wisely organize such a task. The scheme I developed above seems to me somewhat unprofessional. Isn't it? How would I organize it in more professional way? Or is it okay

Comment: Do some proper normalization in 3NF: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization A single database server can handle lots of requests per second, a connection pool can help as well. If you have to scale out, you can use database replication. But don't forget that databases are made to handle large amounts of data for many concurrent users. MySQL aint't the best performing beast, but for many situations it will do fine.